# How to add a new collection in Solr?

Tags: solr

What are the steps for adding a new collection in the existing core of the Apache Solr?

Currently I have a folder

**solr>example>example-schemaless>solr>collection1**

I want to create a new collection named *recipe*, how I could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing that:

- Copy/paste existing *collection1*, and rename it to *recipe*, then you probably will need to update some config files, to reflect these changes (it looks like a error-prone method to me, but still usable of course)
- Use **Solr** collection API to create new collection by making call on this endpoint */admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=name&numShards=number&replicationFactor=number&maxShardsPerNode=number&createNodeSet=nodelist&collection.configName=configname*. For more information take a look here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api1

Comment: It Shows The Following Error :new_core: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core new_core: Error loading solr config from solr/new_core/conf/solrconfig.xml

Comment: @AswinRaghavan, interesting error, probably something wrong with configuration or invocation